# Nginx/Unicorn not showing changes upon deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I have a weird issue.  We are running Rails 3.2.2, Nginx, and Unicorn.  If we make a text change to index.html.erb for example then deploy the change doesn't show.

If I look at the file on the production server I can see the change is in fact sitting in the 'current' directory.  So I know its been released correctly.

Its as if Unicorn isn't updating itself or restarting correctly ( even though I'm restarting upon deploy).

Even weirder - I changed the apps email smtp settings.  After deploying I get SMTP 535 bad username/password.  However, if I refresh like 3 times it works.  Again - could this be some sort of nginx/unicorn worker caching old code?

I have to deploy this project today so am under some pressure to figure this out.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add the contents of your Unicorn configuration (generally `config/unicorn.rb`)

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out? I have a similar setup, Rails 3.2.9/nginx/unicorn, and changes to my erb templates don't show when I deploy. Let us know if you made any progress!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different variables involved. Depending on how you've configured Unicorn, you may need to send `unicorn master` a [USR2 signal](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html) signal to spin up a new master process, followed by a QUIT signal to the old unicorn master to reap it.

Depending on the production server environment and deployment mechnaism, you may be able to leverage a tool like [foreman](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/) to make managing your unicorns a bit easier when deploying.